# AngularJS - Undefined file in upload dialog box

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

i have some problems with AngularJS + Material and a upload dialog box. I think that the cause is about scoping because when i select a file to upload and click on **md-button**, the console.log command (in the controller block) shows me "***file is undefined***" and to backend doesn't arrive data.

This is my code.

**template**

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Carica foto">
  <form ng-cloak>
    <md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <h2>Upload photo</h2>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="cancel()">
          <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_close_24px.svg" aria-label="Close dialog"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-dialog-content>
      <div class="md-dialog-content">
        <p>Choose photo</p>
        <br/><br/>
        <input type = "file" file-model="fotoBadge"/>
      </div>
    </md-dialog-content>
    <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
      <span flex></span>
      <md-button ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload</md-button>
    </md-dialog-actions>
  </form>
</md-dialog>
```

**directive**

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
         var modelSetter = model.assign;

         element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
               modelSetter(scope, element[0].files);
            });
         });
        }
   };
}]);
```

**service**

```
app.service('fileUploadSrv', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);

    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}    })
    .success(function(){
               })
    .error(function(){
               });      }
}]);
```

**controller**

```
  function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.hide = function() {
      $mdDialog.hide();
    };
    $scope.cancel = function() {
      $mdDialog.cancel();
    };
    $scope.uploadFile = function(answer) {
       var file = $scope.fotoBadge;

       console.log('file is ' + file);

       var uploadUrl = "/be/fileUpload";
       fileUploadSrv.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);

      $mdDialog.hide(answer);
    };
  }
```

Thanks at all in advance.

Davide

Comment: Your code seems okay - https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/vXYOdW?editors=1010

Comment: Hi, i solved!! the mistake was on the **controller** : i need to get the DOM element through `document.querySelector("#fotoBadge")` instead `$scope.fotoBadge` (obviously it's necessary to add **id** parameters to the input tag  `<input type="input" id="fotoBadge" file-model="fotoBadge">` )